# Automatically restarting HHVM when it stops responding but process not dead

Tags: nginx, monitoring, daemon, hhvm

I'm having a problem where every 12-24 hours, HHVM crashes but it seems to leave the process running. It seems most providers just use php5-fpm as a failover within nginx for stability. However, this won't restart the non-responsive hhvm instance.

Since the process is left running, most server monitoring solutions will see it as a live daemon, and not restart it. HTTP monitoring can be slow to react.

Is it possible to trigger the hhvm restart on failover? If not, what would be the best solution to ensure a listening daemon that's non responsive is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

[kristapsk](https://github.com/kristapsk) posted a solution on Official bug regarding this topic.
This is the script he told to add to cron to be executed every 2 minutes.

I have modified it a bit to make it work with prebuilt packages of HHVM.

```
#! /bin/bash
PID="`cat /var/run/hhvm/pid`"

if [ "$PID" == "" ]; then
    echo No PID, starting up
    /etc/init.d/hhvm start
else
    if [ "`ps ax -o pid | grep $PID`" == "" ]; then
        echo HHVM PID $PID not running, starting up
        # Stop, just in case, if crashed. Else you would get:
        #  * WARNING: hhvm.83 has already been started
        /etc/init.d/hhvm stop
        /etc/init.d/hhvm start
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I believe this is a simple cron script to check to make sure the HHVM process is still running. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue of checking whether a still "listening" process has just become unresponsive.

Comment: @etc, HHVM crashes when it becomes unresponsive :-)

Comment: Not always. It's actually a fairly well documented issue.

Comment: @etc, I was speaking of my experience of more than six months. But in case what you say actually happens, then execute a script from cron that echoes hello world and then compare the output.

Comment: This is an issue I've even discussed with the Facebook HHVM devs. It happens. What you suggest doesn't test the listening process - and if I have fpm as a fallback, that means I can't test the app server's response itself.

Comment: @etc, in the cases you describe (which I also seem to be experiencing), is HHVM still listening? Or is it simply timing out? If it's the former, you might be able to adapt this cron to do something like `lsof -i TCP:9000` instead of looking for the PID.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment on the other answer, a good option when you have a fallback to php and you want to ensure that HHVM is the one that responded is to use the solution from [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40178827/365695) with one change, in your status script do a check for:

```
if (defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
  echo 'status';
}
```

The two solutions combined will handle all of hhvm's possible ways of crashing.