# How to handle HHVM crash or when it becomes unresponsive?

Tags: cron, monitoring, hhvm

Current state is like this: Nginx -> HHVM -> PHP5-FPM.

When HHVM crashes (quite often) it returns 502 error.

I did @fallback workaround to nginx configuration, but I need to manually restart hhvm.

here [Automatically restarting HHVM when it stops responding but process not dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047756/automatically-restarting-hhvm-when-it-stops-responding-but-process-not-dead) some PID listener cron is described, but sometimes hhvm just unresponsive with existing pid.

How to monitor this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same problem - HHVM becomes unresponsive randomly (I haven't figured out why yet)

Here is how I monitor HHVM:

I created a simple status.php:

```
<?php echo 'status' ?>
```

Then I created status.sh bash file:

```
#! /bin/bash
STATUS="`timeout -s KILL 13 wget -T 13 -q -O -  http://domain.com/status.php`"
if [ "$STATUS" != "status" ]
then
  /etc/init.d/hhvm stop
  /etc/init.d/hhvm start
fi
```

Then I created a cron job that runs every minute:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/camera.new/status.sh
```

You can adjust timeout (currently - 13s). I think if HHVM doesn't run the simple status.php file for 13s it is time to restart.

Comment: Hey, 
I've ended up with similar solution. Strange thing is that after I started monitoring HHVM it became unresponsive less frequent )).

Answer (score 0):

How about just monitoring your website. With [WDT.io](https://wdt.io) you'd create an outbound watchdog timer with your website's address so it would be tested every minute and alert you if it returns the 502 or any other error. That would have the advantage of also finding out if there're any other problems besides HHVM.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The thing is that I have already uptime monitoring tool, I need something specific that will relaunch failed service (HHVM) within OS without need to have it done manually.